# AppBarTheme's Color Property Not Reflecting Overridden inversePrimary in ThemeData's ColorScheme

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to override the `inversePrimary` property in the `ColorScheme` within a `ThemeData`.

Despite setting a custom `inversePrimary` color in the ColorScheme, the `AppBarTheme`'s color property seems to default to purple instead of using the overridden `inversePrimary` color.

Look at bellow code snippet,

```
ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.green,
      inversePrimary: Colors.pink,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
    ),
  )
```

The goal is to have the `AppBar` utilize the overridden `inversePrimary` color from the ColorScheme.However, it's still displaying the default purple color.

I've verified that the `ColorScheme` is properly configured with the custom `inversePrimary` color. Could anyone assist in understanding why the `AppBarTheme`'s `color` property isn't reflecting this overridden color and provide guidance on how to make it work as intended?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The context at this "level" does not contain the new `ColorScheme` yet. There must be at least 1 "closure level" (e.g. a build(er) function) between them, in order for anything to be merged into the sub-context.

Comment: The simplified version of what @MarianTheisen says, is that you cannot use the `inversePrimary` like this: `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary`, because you are initializing it here in the previous lines. So you could directly pass `Colors.pink` here in the `AppBarTheme` object.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a custom `ColorScheme` and attempting to use the `inversePrimary` color from that scheme within the `AppBarTheme`. The issue might be arising from the way the inversePrimary color is being accessed or calculated within the `AppBarTheme`. Here's a revised version of your code that explicitly sets the `inversePrimary` color in the `AppBarTheme`:

```
ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    primaryColorDark: Colors.pink,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  ),
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.transparent, // Set your desired app bar color here
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
    foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
  ),
)
```

`ColorScheme.fromSwatch` creates a color scheme using a primary color and a darker primary color (`primaryColorDark`). You can adjust these according to your preferences.

`AppBarTheme` is configured with `backgroundColor` and `foregroundColor` properties explicitly taken from the defined `ColorScheme`.

`color: Colors.transparent` is set to make the app bar transparent. You can replace this with the desired color for the app bar.

Now You can change as needed to match your designs requirements.